# Calculation of de Rham cohomology of abelian varieties/ jacobian varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties, p-adic-hodge-theory, derham-cohomology

It's known that for a elliptic curve like $E:y^2=x(x-1)(x-t)$ we have a basis $\frac{dx}{y}, \frac{xdx}{y}$ for $H_{dR}^1(E)$. But find such a basis is not an easy thing. I wonder for a general abelian variety or a jacobian variety over a smooth curve is there a way to write out an basis for $H_{dR}^1$ (algebraic de Rham)  explicitly?

In my settings, suppose $K$ is an finite unramified extension of $\mathbb Q_p$ and $C$ is a curve defined over $K$ (smooth projective). Let $J$ be its jacobian. I need to calculate the matrix of Frobenius on $H_{dR}^1(J)$ by the comparison theorem (or using rigid cohomology).

For rigid cohomology I need to find a basis for $H_{dR}^1(J)$ and lift Frobenius to the weak completion of $J$. But then I'm stuck. Firstly I don't know how to find a canonical basis and I don't know how to find the weak completion since I know nothing about the equation of $J$.

Anything about calculating the frobenius would be of help. Thanks.

Comment: Find a plane model for the curve (e. G. by projecting).  Compute the adjoint ideal, and use it to construct a basis for the canonical system of the original curve.  It’s done (with some examples) in ACGH, and there are enough search terms in this comment to find the packages for your favorite CAS.